# Calc 2 visualizing equations in 3D

Tags: calculus, visualization

Is there a way to create and visualize a 3D object given an equation? I am currently studying calc 2 and would really like to be able to interact or view the equations I am given. For example, I have this problem: [image]

I would like to be able to rotate it around whatever axis I want in order to create the 3D shape. Is this possible? I doesn't have to tell me the area, I just want a 3d shape.

Thanks!

Comment: The question finds two volumes of revolution. Do you know the formula for such calculations? Can you search in the textbook that you took this picture from? (About the x-axis, it’s often called the disk method; about the y-axis, the washer method)

Comment: Yes, I know and have memorized the formula. I am using this question as an example and would like to see a way to visualize area not automatically calculate it.

Comment: See also [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=volume+of+revolution+for+y%3Dx*sin%28x%29+from+x%3D1+to+x%3D5+about+the+line+y%3D-2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/) is a good place to check visualization.

In particular, you can try this: https://www.geogebra.org/m/zBRtUVfR

[image]

Comment: That's awesome! Do you know of any way to fill the shape after it has been rotated? I want it to look like it doesn't have infinitesimally thin edges if you know what I mean.

Comment: Also, how would you suggest I go about learning how to use GeoGebra. I checked it out but had no luck with it. I asked other people I knew and they also didn't really know. They had only seen it been used before. Thanks for the time you put into this answer!

Comment: @Cyclist: you can try this one: https://www.geogebra.org/m/cKD7Erm6

Comment: @Cyclist: These tutorials may be helpful: https://www.geogebra.org/a/14?lang=en